# Is there code that can detect the difference between redirected page or refreshed page (loading for the first time)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, page-refresh

How do I determine if the page was refreshed (F5) or redirected from another page (responce.redirect)?

What code could I use to detect that in JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: code in javascript or jquery will be welcomed

Comment: You should clarify what you need this for.

Comment: Why did you tag this C#, but ask for code in JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: i had done the code in C# but it is failing on page load using protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
     protected override object SaveViewState()

Comment: Uhh, maybe post the code then? Since apparently the problem you're experiencing is occurring with the code that you've written. Do you actually want a solution in C#, or JavaScript/jQuery? They're completely different languages...

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value in `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];` It should be null I guess if it is refreshed or the same url.

Comment: If you refresh, the browser should send the same headers as before, including the same referer. And also, you can't be sure that a referer is ever sent.

Comment: yeah and if you keep that referer in Session, you can check if it is changed or still the same. I know that it won't work in all cases but it is something.

Comment: This is in no way a 100% foolproof solution. Many proxies & firewalls remove the referrer header from requests.

Answer (score 1):

In case of redirect, UrlReferrer will contain the Url of previous page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

In a simple refresh, it will be NULL.

Comment: This is in no way a 100% foolproof solution. Many proxies & firewalls remove the referrer header from requests.

Comment: No,it is giving me same url for refresh also

Comment: simple refresh it wont be null because the header with referrer holds the old value . @MayP got any workaround to it .

Answer (score 0):

You can't. (This is all there is to it, now let's make it 30 chars long...)

Comment: Why is this being down voted? The question is tagged JavaScript and jQuery. This answer is the most correct so far IMHO.

Comment: @Pabuc: The thing is, no one really knows for sure *what* the question is asking. The original tag and the first comment from the author did not agree.